# Full text search Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, full-text-search

have a 10000+ entries in a Firesore collection. From these 10000+ rows some of them are duplicate or even triplicates. Let's imagine that a record is like { "name":"toy My Home bla bla bla" } and some other record is { "name":"My Home toy bla bla bla bla bla bla" }
What I want to do is to have a way to see starting from first record to see that these two are same based on "My toy" text and do some action.

How could I achieve this ?

Comment: Please don't repeat questions on Stack Overflow.  The other question was closed for a reason.  Firestore can't perform this sort of query and you will need another search engine to accomplish this.  However, questions that are seeking recommendations for products are off topic here.  I suggest posting to a discussion forum that allows for this sort of question, such as Reddit.

Comment: Maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444) will help.